# How to install Ruby version >= 2.0 for Vagrant in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, vagrant, vagrant-plugin

I have an `EC2` instance in `Amazon` running `Ubuntu 14.4.3`. 
Which will run `Vagrant` and deploy some vm's using `vagrant-aws` plugin.
But everytime that I try to install the plugin gives me the follow error:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-25-56-198:~$ vagrant plugin install vagrant-aws
Installing the 'vagrant-aws' plugin. This can take a few minutes...
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:388:in `ensure_required_ruby_version_met': net-ssh requires Ruby version >= 2.0. (Gem::InstallError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:156:in `install'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:297:in `block in install'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:270:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:270:in `each_with_index'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:270:in `install'
    from /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/commands/plugin/action/install_gem.rb:65:in `block in call'
    from /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/commands/plugin/gem_helper.rb:42:in `block in with_environment'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/user_interaction.rb:40:in `use_ui'
    from /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/commands/plugin/gem_helper.rb:41:in `with_environment'
    from /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/commands/plugin/action/install_gem.rb:52:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/commands/plugin/action/bundler_check.rb:20:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/runner.rb:69:in `block in run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/runner.rb:69:in `run'
    from /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/commands/plugin/command/base.rb:17:in `action'
    from /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/commands/plugin/command/install.rb:27:in `execute'
    from /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/commands/plugin/command/root.rb:56:in `execute'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/cli.rb:38:in `execute'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/environment.rb:484:in `cli'
    from /usr/bin/vagrant:127:in `<main>'
```

I have the same version of `Ubuntu` in my `desktop` machine and didn't have this issue. What am I doing wrong ? I tried to remove `ruby1.9` and install only `ruby2.2` but still giving the same error.

EDIT

```
ubuntu@ip-172-25-56-198:~$ ruby -v
ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-linux]
```

Vagrant installs ruby1.9, even if I have the newer version installed!

```
root@ip-172-31-29-138:/tmp# apt-get install -y vagrant
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  ruby1.9.1
Suggested packages:
  ruby1.9.1-examples ri1.9.1 graphviz ruby1.9.1-dev virtualbox
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ruby1.9.1 vagrant
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/425 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1.898 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package ruby1.9.1.
(Reading database ... 146549 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../ruby1.9.1_1%3a1.9.3.551-2bbox1~trusty1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking ruby1.9.1 (1:1.9.3.551-2bbox1~trusty1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package vagrant.
Preparing to unpack .../vagrant_1.4.3-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking vagrant (1.4.3-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up ruby1.9.1 (1:1.9.3.551-2bbox1~trusty1) ...
Setting up vagrant (1.4.3-1) ...
```

And then, the same error again:

```
root@ip-172-25-56-198:/tmp# vagrant plugin install vagrant-aws
Installing the 'vagrant-aws' plugin. This can take a few minutes...
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:388:in `ensure_required_ruby_version_met': net-ssh requires Ruby version >= 2.0. (Gem::InstallError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:156:in `install'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:297:in `block in install'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:270:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:270:in `each_with_index'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:270:in `install'
    from /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/commands/plugin/action/install_gem.rb:65:in `block in call'
    from /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/commands/plugin/gem_helper.rb:42:in `block in with_environment'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/user_interaction.rb:40:in `use_ui'
    from /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/commands/plugin/gem_helper.rb:41:in `with_environment'
    from /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/commands/plugin/action/install_gem.rb:52:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/commands/plugin/action/bundler_check.rb:20:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/runner.rb:69:in `block in run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/runner.rb:69:in `run'
    from /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/commands/plugin/command/base.rb:17:in `action'
    from /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/commands/plugin/command/install.rb:27:in `execute'
    from /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/commands/plugin/command/root.rb:56:in `execute'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/cli.rb:38:in `execute'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/environment.rb:484:in `cli'
    from /usr/bin/vagrant:127:in `<main>'
```

Comment: That's not possible :) What does the `ruby -v` return?

Comment: Well, it seems that vagrant has a hard dependency on ruby 1.9, so you will need to manually install the ruby 2.2 and ensure that the 2.2 goes first in the PATH. So by the time you run `vagrant plugin install vagrant-aws`, `ruby -v` should return `2.2.3`,

Comment: whats you vagrant version ?

Comment: Having this same exact problem.  I also tried the same exact steps- I wonder if it was recently updated because I haven't had this issue in the past.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that vagrant has a hard dependency on ruby 1.9 (check by `ruby -v`).

So you will need to manually install the ruby 2.2 and ensure that the 2.2 goes first in the `PATH`. Then try to install the plugin again by:

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-aws
```

Answer (score 0):

Run into exact same problem.  Solved by installing latest vagrant from official download page.

It seems that the vagrant on ubuntu 14 has a hard dependency on ruby 1.9 as kenorb said.  Vagrant official installation page also suggests that you don't install vagrant by OS package repos.